# Errores en filtro de columnas en datagridview 'System.NotSupportedException' DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview, filtro

Me sale ese error junto con este

Additional information: Invalid expression: [FechaFactura]='11/01/2020 04:16:02 p.m.'

al filtrar por fecha los otros filtros que no son fecha si los filtra, esto es lo que use para poner los filtros en el datagridview:

```
 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                        bs.DataSource = oDsHDRCelMousClic.Tables[0];
                        oDsHDRCelMousClic.BeginInit();
                        grdDET.DataSource = bs;
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn item in grdDET.Columns)
                        {
                            item.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(item.HeaderCell);

                        }
```

me imagino que es el formato de la fecha pero como lo cambio? eso lo trae de la bd creo, porque antes el usuario selecciona la fecha de un datetimepicker y ahí no sale tiempo ni am ni pm solo la fecha, ese es un problema.

el otro es que al darle click en los filtros salen unas letras chinas o no se de donde
[image: letras chinas en click en filtro]

y en la primera opción si le doy click sale un recuadro de cosas mas avanzadas de filtrado pero todo esta en chino o no se que lenguaje, la dll la baje de aquí https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataGridViewAutoFilter/1.0.0 me imagino que ahí esta el problema

[image: recuadro con letras chinas]

el tercer problema es que al darle click en el encabezado de cada columna para ordenar los datos las primeras 2 columnas del lado izquierdo si funcionan bien y en la 5 también pero en las otras si le doy click si las ordena pero me hace lo que tengo en el botón CFD que están a la derecha, este es el código de cuando le dan click a los botones

```
private void grdDET_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (grdDET.Columns["CFD"].DisplayIndex == 8 || grdDET.Columns["Aperak"].DisplayIndex == 9)
        //{

            try
            {
                String Ruta = String.Empty;
                String nombre_xml = String.Empty;
                String strXML = String.Empty;
                String Id_Cnsc_CFD = String.Empty;
                //DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
                String CadenaConexion = String.Empty;

                #region Leemos Archivo de Configuración
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

                XmlNode appSettingsNode =
                  xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/rutas");

                if (appSettingsNode != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode node in appSettingsNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        string value = node.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
                        string keyName = node.Attributes["key"].Value.ToString();

                        if (keyName == "RutaArchivo")
                            Ruta = value;
                    }

                    if (false == Ruta.EndsWith("\\"))
                    {
                        Ruta += '\\';
                    }

                    if (Directory.Exists(Ruta) == false)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No se encontró el directorio \"" + Ruta + "\".");
                    }

                    foreach (String xmls in Directory.GetFiles(Ruta))
                    {
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(xmls);

                        if (fi.Extension.ToUpper() == ".XML")
                        {
                            File.Delete(fi.FullName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("No se encontró el nodo \"rutas\".");
                }
                #endregion

                //if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                //{
                //    DataGridViewRow row = grdHDR.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                //    grdDET.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                //    //txt3_prov.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                //Id_Cnsc_CFD = e.ColumnIndex.Equals("Id_Cnsc_CFD").ToString().Trim();
                //}

                Id_Cnsc_CFD = grdDET.CurrentRow.Cells["Id_Cnsc_CFD"].Value.ToString().Trim();

                try
                {
                    sp = db.GetStoredProcCommand("eDocResumenEmisor_pUP");

                    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pCveOperacion", DbType.String, "X");
                    db.AddInParameter(sp, "@pId_Cnsc_CFD", DbType.Int32, Id_Cnsc_CFD);

                    oDsDET = db.ExecuteDataSet(sp);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                if (oDsDET.Tables.Count == 1)
                {
                    if (oDsDET.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        if (grdDET.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim() == "CFD")
                        {
                            strXML = oDsDET.Tables[0].Rows[0]["XML"].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        else if (grdDET.CurrentRow.Cells["Aperak"].Value.ToString().Trim() == "Aperak")
                        {
                            strXML = oDsDET.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Aperak"].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        //if (grdDET.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                        //{
                        //    int selectedrowindex = grdDET.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                        //    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = grdDET.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                        //    string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["CFD"].Value);
                        //}
                        //if (a == "CFD")
                        //{
                        //    strXML = oDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["XML"].ToString().Trim();
                        //}
                        //if (a == "Aperak")
                        //{
                        //    strXML = oDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Aperak"].ToString().Trim();
                        //}
                    }
                }

                nombre_xml = System.Guid.NewGuid() + ".XML";

                //Creamos el Archivo APERAK del error...
                using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(Ruta + nombre_xml, 1024))
                {
                    // Add some information to the file.
                    byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(strXML);
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }

                Process.Start(Ruta + nombre_xml);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        //}

    }
```

PD soy nuevo en windows forms

Comment: No utilizas ninguna conversión de fechas en tu consulta SQL?

Comment: yo no hice el sp pero trae esto:                                                         
SELECT    
   Fec_Ini = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), pFec_Ini, 112) + ' 00:00:00')    
  ,Fec_Fin = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), pFec_Fin, 112) + ' 23:59:00')                                                                                                                                                                          antes de Fec_Ini, Fec_Fin, pFec_Ini y pFec_Fin le quite los @ para poner el código aquí

Comment: Intenta quitando las horas en el convert para ver si te sigue mostrando el error en el formato de la fecha.

Comment: Si, sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: o que me recomiendan necesito que funcionen los filtros alguna otra opción?

Answer (score 0):

resulta que actualice o cambie el dll y ya no me muestra los símbolos chinos y sigue enviándome el error, pero ahora en otra clase DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell.cs éste el código donde sale el error

```
private void UpdateFilter()
{
    // Continue only if the selection has changed.
    if (dropDownListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(selectedFilterValue))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Store the new selection value. 
    selectedFilterValue = dropDownListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    // Cast the data source to an IBindingListView.
    IBindingListView data = 
        this.DataGridView.DataSource as IBindingListView;

    Debug.Assert(data != null && data.SupportsFiltering,
        "DataSource is not an IBindingListView or does not support filtering");

    // If the user selection is (All), remove any filter currently 
    // in effect for the column. 
    if (selectedFilterValue.Equals("(All)"))
    {
        data.Filter = FilterWithoutCurrentColumn(data.Filter);
        filtered = false;
        currentColumnFilter = String.Empty;
        return;
    }

    // Declare a variable to store the filter string for this column.
    String newColumnFilter = null;

    // Store the column name in a form acceptable to the Filter property, 
    // using a backslash to escape any closing square brackets. 
    String columnProperty = 
        OwningColumn.DataPropertyName.Replace("]", @"\]");

    // Determine the column filter string based on the user selection.
    // For (Blanks) and (NonBlanks), the filter string determines whether
    // the column value is null or an empty string. Otherwise, the filter
    // string determines whether the column value is the selected value. 
    switch (selectedFilterValue)
    {
        case "(Blanks)":
            newColumnFilter = String.Format(
                "LEN(ISNULL(CONVERT([{0}],'System.String'),''))=0",
                columnProperty);
            break;
        case "(NonBlanks)":
            newColumnFilter = String.Format(
                "LEN(ISNULL(CONVERT([{0}],'System.String'),''))>0",
                columnProperty);
            break;
        default:
            newColumnFilter = String.Format("[{0}]='{1}'",
                columnProperty,
                ((String)filters[selectedFilterValue])
                .Replace("'", "''"));  
            break;
    }

    // Determine the new filter string by removing the previous column 
    // filter string from the BindingSource.Filter value, then appending 
    // the new column filter string, using " AND " as appropriate. 
    String newFilter = FilterWithoutCurrentColumn(data.Filter);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newFilter))
    {
        newFilter += newColumnFilter;
    }
    else
    {
        newFilter += " AND " + newColumnFilter;
    }


    // Set the filter to the new value.
    try
    {
        data.Filter = newFilter;
    }
    catch (InvalidExpressionException ex)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(
            "Invalid expression: " + newFilter, ex);
    }

    // Indicate that the column is currently filtered
    // and store the new column filter for use by subsequent
    // calls to the FilterWithoutCurrentColumn method. 
    filtered = true;
    currentColumnFilter = newColumnFilter;
}
```

aquí me sale ese error ahora

[image: error]